# Highlight the second instance of a combination

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need a conditional formatting formula that will highlight the second instance of a combination of values from two columns. For example, Column A is a person's name and Column B is a drop down with three options (Street Address, Phone Number, and Email Address).

If Row 2 says John Smith (Column A) and Street Address (Column B) and Row 7 also says John Smith (Column A) and Street Address (Column B), what conditional formatting formula would I use to highlight row 7 as duplicate information?

Comment: All instances other than the first

Answer (score 1):

Select both entire columns A and B and then apply conditional formatting with the following formula

`=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1,$A1,$B$1:$B1,$B1)>1`

The $ signs should be exactly as shown

That counts, for each row, that row and the rows above only which exactly match in both columns. If the count is >1 then the current row must be a duplicate and it is formatted.

Assumes Excel 2007 or later